# Represent a graph

Tags: r

I have the next data, with dput(head(titanic7,20))

```
structure(list(PassengerId = 1:20, Survived = c("NO", "YES", 
"YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", 
"NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "NO", "YES", "NO", "YES"), Pclass = c(3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), Name = c("Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)", 
"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)", 
"Allen, Mr. William Henry", "Moran, Mr. James", "McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J", 
"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard", "Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)", 
"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)", "Sandstrom, Miss. Marguerite Rut", 
"Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth", "Saundercock, Mr. William Henry", 
"Andersson, Mr. Anders Johan", "Vestrom, Miss. Hulda Amanda Adolfina", 
"Hewlett, Mrs. (Mary D Kingcome)", "Rice, Master. Eugene", "Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene", 
"Vander Planke, Mrs. Julius (Emelia Maria Vandemoortele)", "Masselmani, Mrs. Fatima"
), Sex = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "female", "female", "male", "male", "female", "female"
), Age = c(22, 38, 26, 35, 35, 26, 54, 2, 27, 14, 4, 58, 20, 
39, 14, 55, 2, 31, 31, 31), SibSp = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Parch = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Ticket = c("A/5 21171", "PC 17599", "STON/O2. 3101282", 
"113803", "373450", "330877", "17463", "349909", "347742", "237736", 
"PP 9549", "113783", "A/5. 2151", "347082", "350406", "248706", 
"382652", "244373", "345763", "2649"), Fare = c(7.25, 71.2833, 
7.925, 53.1, 8.05, 8.4583, 51.8625, 21.075, 11.1333, 30.0708, 
16.7, 26.55, 8.05, 31.275, 7.8542, 16, 29.125, 13, 18, 7.225), 
    Embarked = c("S", "C", "S", "S", "S", "Q", "S", "S", "S", 
    "C", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "Q", "S", "S", "C"), Title = c("Mr", 
    "Mrs", "Miss", "Mrs", "Mr", "Mr", "Mr", "Master", "Mrs", 
    "Mrs", "Miss", "Miss", "Mr", "Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Master", 
    "Mr", "Mrs", "Mrs"), agecat = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), .Label = c("<10", "10-20", "20-30", "30-40", "40-50", 
    "50-60", "60-70", ">70"), class = "factor"), Familysize = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 
    5L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Sigleton = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("SibSp", 
"Parch"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 
12L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L), 8L, c(0L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 18L), 10L, 13L, 
    7L, 16L), group_sizes = c(10L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
    SibSp = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), Parch = c(0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("SibSp", 
"Parch"), drop = TRUE))
```

When making bar graphs with the number of passengers that have survived for each "SEX" and "Pclass" value, I did so:

```
 titanic7 %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(Sex, fill = Survived))
 titanic7 %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(Pclass, fill = Survived))
```

But is there any way to do it using a single graphic?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please don't post data as an image. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(titanic7)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(titanic7, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **facet_grid**

```
titanic7 %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(Sex, fill = Survived)) + facet_grid(.~ Pclass)
```

[image: titanic sex and survived count]

Comment: Thank you for the help!!